# Returning player that belongs in two organization lists

Tags: python

I'm using a list comprehension to find an object that matches in two lists and return the object for its property. I know the object **ALWAYS** exists in both lists and no other item in the lists are shared but I don't know which one it is so I can't just reference it from the list.

The code I can give you is:

```
class BaseballCard:

    ...

    @staticmethod
    def load_from_matching_player_with_other_org(organization, other_org):
        """Determine matching pair of the same player and create Baseball Card."""
        return BaseballCard(*[player for player in organization.players if player in other_org][0].stats)

     ...
```

Is there a better or simpler way to do this part?

```
[player for player in organization.players if player in other_org][0]
```

**Topic slightly changed to protect sensitive data**

Comment: This question was [discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/conversation/discussion-about-generic-identifiers-in-q-73664).

Comment: moar downvotes, plz. They def make me better developer. As they say, "A downvote is worth a trillion comments."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with a generator expression. Here instead of creating a list of all matching items `next` will simply return the first item from the generator passed to it:

```
next(player for player in organization.players if player in other_org.players).stats
```

Just in case `other_org.players` is huge and all items in both lists are `hashable` then better convert `other_org.players` to a set first to support fast lookups:

```
other_org_set = set(other_org.players)
next(player for player in organization.players if player in other_org_set).stats
```

Note that both solutions above assume there's always at least one such maching items, if that's not the case then better return a sentinel value(usually `None` and `object()` are used) from `next` and then try to access `pror` based on the return value from `next`:

```
matching_player = next((player for player in organization.players if player in other_org.players), None)
if matching_player is not None:
    return BaseballCard(matching_player.stats)
```